# Создание градиента фона ячейки

Tags: swift, uitableview, tableview

Как создать градиент фона ячейки?

Comment: а что не получается? создать UIImage с градиентом или полученный градиент поставить в ячейку?

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko Вы имеете ввиду картинку поставить на задний фон ячейки?))

Comment: тогда встречный вопрос, а что имеете ввиду вы?

Comment: Через CAGradientLayer. Вот тут туториал: https://www.raywenderlich.com/90693/modern-core-graphics-with-swift-part-2

Comment: в результате этого туториала вы получаете UIImage, который вам надо подложить под все сабвью в ячейке